# I had deployed the test application on Production on Google Cloud via App Engine, But URL still accessible

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had deployed the test application on Production on Google Cloud via App Engine and i could not see the instance is being created as its serverless it could or it could not create the instance.
But I am concerned about the billing since the URL was still running like on :

**Example:** http://mytestproject-123456.appspot.com/

So I disabled the billing for the project and also the application from the App Engine settings.

Could someone please help or suggest.
Is any action still required to stop the billing if there is any since I had deployed the application on Production and the url was accessible.

1.And If delete the whole project will it work?

If yes please tell the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the app from serving requests and running instances, you can [disable the application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/?csw=1#disabling_an_application). This way you will not be getting billed for that. Basically, there is no need to delete a billing account or the project to just stop serving requests. Please be aware that you still might be charged for storage, or other GCP services that you are using if applicable.

I would say that you do not need to do anything else. For future reference, before deploying a service, a good practice is to [test it locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) before deploying and starting to serve requests from users.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about the Standard Environment; if i am right, you can see the number of instances by going in the console, choosing your project in the selection control on top of the page. After this, in the left column, select App Engine, and, in the page that shows up, you can see the `instances` tab. There you will find all the running instances, if any.

If you are using other resources, they will be billed accordingly. If you are not, disabling the application is all you need to protect yourself against unwanted billing.

Hope this helps.

[image]